# Apache2 Two virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I have two virtual hosts on one server:
srv-08.zone08.edu:80
tulip.zone08.edu:8088

I need to get nothing, when I put srv-08.zone08.edu:8088.

File /etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost srv-08.zone08.edu:80
NameVirtualHost tulip.zone08.edu:8088
Listen 80
Listen 8088
```

File config srv-08.zone08.edu (few first lines):

```
<VirtualHost srv-08.zone08.edu:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@zone08.edu
  ServerName srv-08.zone08.edu
***
```

File config tulip.zone08.edu (few first lines):

```
<VirtualHost tulip.zone08.edu:8088>
  ServerAdmin admin@zone08.edu
  ServerName tulip.zone08.edu
***
```

I think, it's enough to change VirtualHost (it was just ) and NameVirtualHost. 
But it's not enough... ( And in this way, my hosts aren't visible from other connected pc.
Any ideas?

Cofig file:

```
<VirtualHost tulip.zone08.edu:8088> 
  ServerAdmin admin@zone08.edu 
  ServerName tulip.zone08.edu 
  DocumentRoot /usr/apache 
  ErrorLog /home/usr/apache2.log 

  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} srv-08.zone08.edu 
  RewriteRule (.*) http://srv-08.zone08.edu/$1 

  <Directory "/usr/apache"> 
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow 
    Deny from all 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Config is right. everything works, except RewriteEngine and right hostnames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have them on the same server, and the server is listening to both ports, you cannot get just nothing when you connect to a port that Apache is actually handling. There are some various things you can do, that may or may not be what you want, though. I'll try to see if I can help you with them.

First, it's better to put the IP address of the system rather than the hostname in your config file. That way, even if you are having DNS troubles, it won't confuse Apache.

Here's a new config for the tulip server, just remember to put your own actual IP address instead of 1.2.3.4 that I'm using. You also need to fix a path to a usable log fiel where I've written PATH-TO-LOGFILE

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:8088> 
  ServerAdmin admin@zone08.edu 
  ServerName tulip.zone08.edu 
  DocumentRoot /usr/apache 
  ErrorLog /home/usr/apache2.log 

  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteLog PATH-TO-LOGFILE
  RewriteLogLevel 3
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} srv-08.zone08.edu 
  RewriteRule (.*) http://srv-08.zone08.edu/$1 [R,L]

  <Directory "/usr/apache"> 
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow 
    Deny from all 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I fixed another spelling error, you had /VintualHost instead of /VirtualHost, and I added some logging for the rewrite procedure. Once you get it running the way you want, you can remove the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel lines, but for now you'll need them to figure out anything I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Hmm... Where I need add this? In config host tulip or to ports? Because when I add this to tulip config - apache2 got error. As about task... Teacher told me make access to host using name and port... But works as only port....

Comment: How did the config look when you had added it? What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make comment with code block (  as for error - it seems that debian can't read command "RewriteEngine"... "Invalid command "RewriteEngine", perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the configuration into your question instead? It's very unreadable in the comments. Also, there's at least one spelling error - you've got <Direcroty> instead of <Directory>, which may be part of the problem. But it's really hard to read in the comment, there may be something else.

Comment: It seems, that thatever I do - server linked hosts via ports, but not Name:port

Comment: Lovely, thanks! That makes it a lot easier to read! One thing I see immediately is that you left out the "http" part in the RewriteRule. I'm editing my previous answer to make it a bit clearer, and include some more logging

Comment: I think, added IP is not good idea. I need 2 right address, not 4. If I added ip in conf - I get links only with port, not by name and port.

Comment: As to DNS. I don't have it. I put note to /etc/hosts... I have doubt with it - that if this note don't give me access with name:port?

Comment: Mod_rewrite comes with apache. As for the IP address - there has to be some connection between the hostname and a valid IP adress, otherwise nobody will ever be able to reach your system on any port!

Comment: It's just a lab work. So I don't care for other. I just need to do right access. Only with: "tulip.zone08.edu:8088" or "srv-08.zone08.edu:80". Other variants not valid.

Comment: So, it seems that for tulip rewrite is works. Then put "srv-08.zone08.edu:8088" it says, that "incorrect redirect page". I think it's ok. Or not?

Comment: Thanks... I done my work... Now just redirect invalid address.